# Generate signed bundle errors (Unresolved references) only in release mode

Tags: android, android-build, android-build-type, android-signing

I finalized my app and it ran successfully in debug mode without any errors. I also tried to generate signed apk/abb in `debug mode`, and all went well.

Now, my issue is that whenever I try to generate a signed apk/abb in `release mode` I get the following errors during the build process:

- Unresolved reference: repeatOnLifecycle
- Unresolved reference: bindingAdapterPosition
- Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

**An example of how I use bindingAdapterPosition:**

```
class UserFixedIssueViewHolder(
        private val binding: ItemIssueFixedBinding,
        private val onReopenClicked: (issueIndex: Int) -> Unit
    ) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(issue: UserIssue) {
            binding.apply {
                reOpenBtn.setOnClickListener {
                    onReopenClicked(bindingAdapterPosition)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**An example of how I use repeatOnLifeCycle:**

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                launch {
                       viewModel.myStateFlow.collect {
                       //do something
                       }
                }
           }
 }
```

The errors `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` point to the `.collect`
line above.

**I tried the following with no success:**

1. Deleting the .idea folder
2. Invalidate cache and restart
3. Cleaning and rebuilding project
4. Updating Android Studio to 2021.3.1

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

- Unresolved reference: repeatOnLifecycle
- Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

To fix these errors when generating a signed bundle in `release mode` you should add this extra dependency: `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"`

To fix the

- Unresolved reference: bindingAdapterPosition

You must manually add the recyclerView dependency to gradle:

```
implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
// For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0")
```

It is weird that these errors does not show up when building app in debug mode.